# VBA: Reduce time to check if network drive is available

Tags: vba, network-drive

I have the following code to check if the network drive 192.168.50.175 is available to my computer.

```
Public Sub check_if_drive_exists()
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Debug.Print "---"
    Debug.Print fso.driveExists("\\192.168.50.175\MyFolder")
End Sub
```

If the drive is available, I instantly get "True" on VBA immediate window. But if it is not, I have to wait sometimes over 30 seconds to obtain "False".

So my question is:
**Is there any way to reduce that time?**
I cannot understand why driveExists method takes so much time to give the "False" result. Actually that time is quite variable, but always long (i.e. several seconds).

Secondary, I noticed that if I write only the drive IPv4 address alone "\192.168.50.175" the method fails, but if I add the root folder "\192.168.50.175\MyFolder" it works fine. Why? After all the method is checking if the drive exists, not the folder!

Many thanks for the attention

Comment: Please, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/driveexists-method)... "\192.168.50.175" is the **root of the drive**, not the drive. `drivespec` = "A drive letter or a path specification for the root of the drive". This function works for your computer of for computer in the network. In case of network, if the drive is found, it immediately returns `True`. If not, **it keeps searching on the network**. According to its complexity (on line computers) it return `False` only after it explored all the network.

Comment: @FaneDuru your comment is very clever, as always. However, I do not want to map the network drive as if it was a local one (i.e. to assign it a drive letter) as the code may run on different computers with different letters (or even not have the drive mapped). It would be nice a way to make the OS to answer instantly if the network drive is available or not before starting to search it in the whole network. Can you give me a hint regarding this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible for the case of `False` response... I have a piece of code able to ping computers in the network (version for only IP: 192.168.50.175).  If computer is connected it returns `True` instantly, but if not, it needs to wait for the host to reply four times (measuring TTL). You can see it running Ping in commander... For the false case, it **returns in about 4 seconds**. If you need it, I can post it as an answer. In fact, I need to leave my office in some minutes. I will look for the function and post it...

Answer (score 3):

Please, try the next way of checking if a computer is online. If you check for the drive, this one must be shared to be accessible... Using Ping, you know that the computer is online and you can access its shared folders:

```
Function GetPingRes(strIP As String) As Boolean
   Dim objPing As Object

   Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}"). _
       ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '" & strIP & "'")

   If objPing.ItemIndex(0).StatusCode = 0 Then GetPingRes = True

   Set objPing = Nothing
End Function
```

It can be tested as:

```
Sub TestGetPingRes()
    Debug.Print GetPingRes("192.168.50.175") 'it returns instantly
    Debug.Print GetPingRes("192.168.50.176") 'it returns after about 4 seconds...
End Sub
```

Comment: @Guille Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: I did it and it worked exactly as you said. I was looking for something even faster that 4 sec, but your solution means anyway a big improvement if compared with my  over 30 sec.
Another idea maybe to make some code to temporary assign a free drive letter to the network drive and then try if it is available with the method driveExists. But I have to find some time to make it. Thanks for your suggestion and code.